# error message "zip file not a content folder, missing jcr_root"

Tags: aem

Getting the error message

> "zip file not a content folder, missing jcr_root"

while i am trying to upload a package in `package manager console of AEM`, though the `package has jcr_root sub folder`.

Comment: How did you create the package? Was it via your Package Manager of the local instance? via curl? or another Java/scripting code?

Comment: I have got the package from someone and I zipped it and tried uploading, while i got that error message.

Comment: yeah, this packages are not normal zip files. The better is to upload to AEM, edit, and rebuild the package using the package manager.

Comment: Every .zip file is not an AEM package. The error is simple, the file that you trying to upload in AEM package manager is not a valid AEM package file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open the .zip, you should see these folders at the very top:

```
jcr_root
META-INF
```

If they are missing or nested inside some *other* folder then the package structure won't be valid.  These will contain other files and folders.  I recommend you download an existing content package, unzip it, then do the same for your and compare the structure and the files to see what may be different/missing.  An example of the contents is found here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/package-manager.html
[image]

Comment: package consists of immediate sub folders "jcr_root" and "META-INF", but still I am getting the error "Missing jcr_root"

Comment: Infact, if i am downloading a package from package manager and zipping it to upload it again, i am getting the same error

Comment: this is the problem when you are zipping again. When you zip then root folder does not start with jcr_root

Comment: I created a zip of my required package and kept it inside the package along with "jcr_root" and "META-INF", and then I uploaded this newly created zip, and it got uploaded. this zip had the name "Archive.zip" while previously whenever I created the zip, it had the name "<filename>.zip". I'm not sure if it was the problem with the name of the zip or a problem with the instance.